django Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use user.set() instead
Hi I have a project in django when I try to  runserver the message above is shown  this is models.py.
class Display(models.Model) :
    url=models.URLField(unique=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=150) 
    
class Display_Data(models.Model) :
    displays = models.ManyToManyField(Display)  
    user= models.ManyToManyField(User)
    choosenum=models.IntegerField()
    puplish_date =models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

and this the views.py:
def submit_operation(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    url = request.POST.get('url')
    text = request.POST.get('title')
    choosenum = request.POST.get('CHOOSE')

    if Display.objects.filter(url=url).exists():
        display = Display.objects.get(url=url)
        display_data = Display_Data.objects.create(choosenum=choosenum, user=request.user,                  date_published=datetime.now())
        display_data.displays.add(display)
    else:
        display = Display.objects.create(url=url, text=text)
        display_data = Display_Data.objects.create(choosenum=choosenum, user=request.user,    date_published=datetime.now())
        display_data.displays.add(display)        # ... (إعادة توجيه المستخدم)

    #return redirect('searchpage') 
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))ype herea

and when i try to refer to vidion saved before the message.
I make a site show video from youtube in a frame and asked a user to value the vidio i saved vidio url and when i want from user to again evluate the vidio the mistake apeer

The reason as for why you are seeing this error is that
not only displays but user field too has many-to-many relationship.

You can’t associate [Display_Data] with a [user] until [Display_Data] has been saved.

reference
So, just like you are associating your displays model instance, you should associate user instance after you have created and saved display_data model instance.
Your models.py:
class Display(models.Model) :
     url=models.URLField(unique=True)
     text = models.CharField(max_length=150) 

class Display_Data(models.Model) :
         displays = models.ManyToManyField(Display)  
         users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
         choosenum = models.IntegerField()
         puplish_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now) 

since m2m field displays is plural, I made users field plural as well for consistency
Your views.py:
def submit_operation(request):
 if request.method == 'POST':
    url = request.POST.get('url')
    text = request.POST.get('title')
    choosenum = request.POST.get('CHOOSE')

    try:
        choosenum = int(choosenum)
    except e:
       raise ValueError("couldn't convert choosenum into int")
       # or you can handle the error in a way you like

    if Display.objects.filter(url=url).exists():
        display = Display.objects.get(url=url)
        display_data = Display_Data.objects.create(choosenum=choosenum, date_published=datetime.now())
        display_data.displays.add(display)
        display_data.users.add(request.user)
    else:
        display = Display.objects.create(url=url, text=text)
        display_data = Display_Data.objects.create(choosenum=choosenum, date_published=datetime.now())
        display_data.displays.add(display)        # ... (إعادة توجيه المستخدم)
        display_data.users.add(request.user)

    #return redirect('searchpage') 
    return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))ype herea

Also:
On your models.py your have defined choosenum as an integer field:
choosenum = models.IntegerField()

But all the data in request.POST is string, so you should convert it to integer:
choosenum = request.POST.get('CHOOSE')

try:
    choosenum = int(choosenum)
except e:
    raise ValueError("couldn't convert choosenum into int")
    # or you can handle the error in a way you like

